# can a class /id name be a table background color

Tags: html

I've designed a table and given it a class and want to style the table background with a class is this possible? Here is the css codes and html codes: the example looked cool that I want to use:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.backgroundColor = ".class/idname"
```

Comment: im unable to change the background of my table to an effect i saw that looks awesome, i was wondering if i could try the above or 
<table class="navigationtable_NB" id="stripe"> instead

Comment: https://codepen.io/YusukeNakaya/pen/xNdvKW

Comment: could i in the css use a code to use the example i want as the background color which i can call by it name Ie background-color:.stripe;

Comment: .navigationtable_NB1 { 
text-shadow: 0px 0px black;letter-spacing: 0.7px;font-size:20.5px;font-family:verdana;font-weight: 400;height:100%;width:100%;margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;border-collapse: separate;display: fixed;vertical-align:center;float:left;
background-color:red;opacity: 1;cursor: pointer;color:#0B3861;padding:0px;}

Comment: this is my code here, its set to be red but i want it to be this new backround i liked how do i do it

Answer (score 0):

No.

Use [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to add and remove classes to your table.

Give your classes the appropriate styling, including background colour, in your CSS.

Also, note that you can give your table a default style in the HTML.

Comment: thanks but i dont seem to see how to use it appropriately, can you help me please.

Comment: Sure, link me to a JSFiddle and I'll take a look where you're going wrong.